# hive installation on ambari host throws error

Tags: hadoop, ambari

```
stderr: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 38, in <module>
    BeforeInstallHook().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 218, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 34, in hook
    install_packages()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 87, in install_packages
    Package(packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 152, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 118, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 45, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name, self.resource.use_repos, self.resource.skip_repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/zypper.py", line 70, in install_package
    shell.checked_call(cmd, sudo=True, logoutput=self.get_logoutput())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/zypper --quiet install --auto-agree-with-licenses --no-confirm hdp-select' returned 4. The following NEW package is going to be installed:
  hdp-select 

The following package is not supported by its vendor:
  hdp-select 

1 new package to install.
Overall download size: 7.0 KiB. After the operation, additional 20.0 KiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/? shows all options] (y): y
Location 'http://10.x.x.x/HDP/suse11sp3/2.x/updates/2.3.0.0/hdp-select/hdp-select-2.3.0.0-2557.noarch.rpm' is temporarily unaccessible.
```

I get the above error while trying to install hive on a new node, i could install some other components successfully to other nodes using the same location mentioned in the error, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logged in the client machine, installed the packages using zypper manually.